# Separately rotating 2 texture coordinates sets for the same object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I've given this a go for a while, but I haven't been able to get favorable results. Basically, I have a sphere with 2 textures. One is blended on top with other and the idea is to have it be a face environment mapping. I want one texture to rotate with the sphere and the other to stay fixed to the initial texture coordinates.

I have tried rotating the GL_TEXTURE matrix of one texture and resetting the other, but this doesn't really do the trick because the texture mapping isn't right when it's rotated certain ways.

Anyone know how i can rotate only one set of texture coordinates and keep the other fixed?

Here's my render code at the moment:

```
glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

glClientActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0);
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[0]);
glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TexturedVertexData3D), &SphereVertexData[0].texCoord);

glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -4.5f);
glRotatef(.00001, .00001, .0, .0);

glClientActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1);
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[1]);
glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TexturedVertexData3D), &SphereVertexData[0].texCoord);

glPopMatrix();

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ADD);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -4.5f);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TexturedVertexData3D), &SphereVertexData[0].vertex);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TexturedVertexData3D), &SphereVertexData[0].normal);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, kSphereNumberOfVertices);

glPopMatrix();

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

rotation += .0001;
```

If anyone needs to see more of what is going on just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two spheres and only issue the glRotatef() to the sphere with the texture that you want rotating. The other sphere would just receive the corresponding glTranslatef() commands. If you are using the alpha channel to blend the textures it should work the same.

Comment: I though about that, but I am worried it will affect the overall performance. There is a bunch of other collision detection and physics math going on that already adds a lot of overhead. Any ideas on how much of a performance hit I'd take as opposed to a different way?

Comment: I've done this before but I only had one model included in the physics and the clone just followed the linear and not rotational changes so it wasn't included in the physics. It was only an additional step for the model drawing which you will probably have anyway with textures that track the model differently.

Comment: This works, although I'm not sure this looks exactly how I desired. With combining the textures i can set the environment to ADD and it blends a bit better. I'll keep experimenting, if i come up with an alternative method I'll post it.